# Best way to open a Socket, allow multiple concurrent access, and close when no more requests pending in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, concurrency

This socket allows only one socket connection to one port at a time on the server. I have built a static class that allows multiple callers but I am not sure how to determine when it is okay to close the socket because there are no more pending requests.

This invloves retriving data from a propritery system through sockets and has a web front end that will have multiple users. Sometimes if the socket is held open for extended periods of time it will stop resoponding, this is why I would like to open the socket, send the requests, and then close it. If a request comes in and the socket is disconnected it needs to reconnect and send the messages, get the responses, and close the socket.

```
public static class SymConnection
{
    private static TcpClient symSocket;
    private static NetworkStream stream;

    private static int _portNumber;
    private static string _hostName;
    private static int commandNumber;
    private static object myLock = "keepThoseSymCmdsInOrder";

    public static string executeCommand(string command)
    {
        incrementCommandCounter();

        lock (myLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExecCommand {0}", commandNumber);
            if (symSocket == null)
            {
                symSocket = new TcpClient(_hostName, _portNumber);
                symSocket.SendTimeout = 5000;
                symSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
                stream = symSocket.GetStream();
            }

            string s = sendCommand(command);


            commandNumber--;
            if (commandNumber == 0)
            {
                stream.Close();
                symSocket.Close();
                symSocket = null;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("ExecCmdEnd {0}", commandNumber);
            return s;
        }
    }

    public static void setConnectionParams(string hostName, int portNumber)
    {
        _hostName = hostName;
        _portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    static void incrementCommandCounter()
    {
        object myObj = "Lock Object";

        lock (myObj)
        {
            commandNumber++;
        }

    }

    static string sendCommand(string command)
    {
        if (!symSocket.Connected) return null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        command = command + "\n";
        Byte[] data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command.Replace("\0xFF", "\0xFF\0xFF"));
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        do
        {
            int input = stream.ReadByte();
            sb.Append((char)input);
        } while (symSocket.Available > 0);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of sockets:

1. Listening sockets. The purpose of these is ***only*** to accept incoming connections. They cannot send or receive. You use `Accept` or `BeginAccept`/`EndAccept` on these.
2. Regular sockets. A connection is established either by `Connect()`ing or by getting accepted by a listener sockets.

A TCP socket can ***never*** be shared by several end points. Each connection is unique between the local socket and the remote socket.

Hence your question is a bit strange and I do not really know what the problem is. Are you being the server (accepting connections) or client (connecting against the server)?

Comment: This is for a web app that acts as a client to a server that only allows one port to be connected to. There are not multiple endpoints as all the commands come from the webapp. You can see here that the way it is determined when to close the connection is not reliable at all.

Comment: A server port can be used by a arbitrary number of clients, not just one. The only thing that would keep the server from accepting more clients is that it do not call `Accept` on the socket again. `You can see here that the way it is determined when to close the connection is not reliable at all` I do not understand that statement.